# Left shift operators in c

Tags: c, bit-shift

I am learning about left shift operators and for multiplying a number with 10 I am using this code.

`long int num=a<<3+a<<1;`

so that no. a first multiplies with 8 and then with 2 and on adding gets a*10 which is stored in num.

But its giving some strange result like `for 5 its 2560, for 6 its 6144.`

Can anyone please explain whats wrong in that implementation?

Comment: Please note that in the real world, there is never a need to use left shift for multiplication by 10. `long int num = a * 10L` works just fine on any system and produces the fastest possible code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format you  are using actually goes this way..

```
num=a<<(3+a)<<1;
```

make some difference between the two application of shift operators by using parenthesis like

```
num=(a<<3)+(a<<1);
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a problem with precedence - the order operators are performed. + binds more tightly than <<, so:

a<<3+a<<1

actually means: a << (a+3) << 1

for 5 that is 5 << 8 << 1 which is 2560 :)

You need: (a<<3) + (a<<1)

See: http://www.swansontec.com/sopc.html for clarification.

Answer (score 1):

What about `warning: suggest parentheses around ‘+’ inside ‘<<’`

Comment: I do not get any warnings after compiling.

Comment: They are only available if enabled.

Comment: @user3160274 Then increase the level of strictness. example `cc -Wall file.c`

Answer (score 0):

`+` is processed before `<<`.

Use `(a<<3)+(a<<1)`

Answer (score 0):

<< operator has less precedence than + operator (Thumb rule Unary Arthematic Relational Logical )

so use braces

```
     int num = (a<<3) + (a<<1);
```

Comment: Both shift and addition are arithmetical operators, how is the thumb rule helping? Also, `&` and `^` are arithmetical, with lower precedence than all relational operators. A better thumb rule: [when in doubt, check an operator precedence table](http://basen.oru.se/c/operators.html).